# Highchart : i want to make a link in drilldown data array

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts

i have a basic drilldown bar chart. i need to make a link with drilldown bar. i am trying with following way,

```
series: [{
        name: 'Things',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Cars',
            y: 4,
            drilldown: 'cars'
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            id: 'cars',
            data: [
                ['Toyota',<a.href ="someurl"> 4</a>],
                ['Opel', <a.href ="someurl"> 4</a>],
                ['Volkswagen', <a.href ="someurl"> 4</a>]
            ]
        }]
    }
```

i understand what i am trying to do is not correct. can anybody help regarding this? 
and I am using highchart in my ruby on rails application and using link_to instead of a.href method.

Answer (score 0):

IN general, points are transleted to SVG element and printed as marker, so adding href is not possible. Only what you can do is catch [click event](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.point.events.click) on the point and call any action.